# How to close forms on a keydown event?

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown

I have a form proFileDialog that called using ShowDialog() on a form mnuForm. I would like to close both both forms when I hit a given key. It seems like I didn't have trouble making this work on a textbox to trigger a messagebox but on with forms I must be doing something wrong. Absolutely nothing happens with the following code when I press the enter key.

```
    void proFileDialog_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
            proFileDialog.Close();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

With proFileDialog.KeyPreview = true it will react to most keys, but I don't get a response to the enter key, or other non letter/number keys.

Comment: Do you want to close the entire application or just the form ?

Comment: It wouldn't matter. Whichever you're willing to teach me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `KeyPreview` property of the form. With this set to `True`, the form will receive key press events before the controls with focus, as below:

[image: key preview property]

Your above code will then work anywhere on the form.

Comment: Nothing happens when I hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I totally misunderstood you, there a couple of ways you can close both forms, one way I can think of is to pass your parent form over to your child form so something like:

```
var pfd = new profFileDialog(this);
pfd.ShowDialog();
```

In your child form:

```
private readonly mnuForm _parentForm;

public profFileDialog(mnuForm parentForm)
{
    _parentForm = parentForm;
    KeyPreview = true; // <-- see Simon's Answer

    // other code ...
}
```

Then simply close both:

```
private void proFileDialog_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.Close();
        _parentForm.Close();
    }
}
```

In case you want to close the entire application (which you probably don't), you can use `Application.Exit();`:

```
private void proFileDialog_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The "if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)" does not trigger when I hit enter. If I switch it to use the "End" key it works.

Comment: @MrBeach You can try `Keys.Return`